# Play Framework JDK Path and Environment Variables configuration file not found

Tags: java, playframework-2.5

So I get the following error whenever I use an activator command. I have followed the error's request, and I have setup my Path and JAVA_HOME variables to their appropriate destinations at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112`
But regardless, I keep getting that error. Plus, I the first error which mentions it can't find the file sbtconfig.txt. I have read the other posts on this topic, none of which have the exact two problems that I have as a combination, however, if you do see one with the same solution, refer it to me.

Thank you in advance.

```
C:\Users\USERNAME>activator ui
ACTIVATOR_HOME=C:\Users\USERNAME\JD Tools\activator-dist-1.3.12
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\USERNAME\JD Tools\activator-dist-1.3.12\bin\..\conf\sbtconfig.txt.

A Java JDK is not installed or can't be found.

Please go to
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
and download a valid Java JDK and install before running Activator.

If you think this message is in error, please check
your environment variables to see if "java.exe" and "javac.exe" are
available via JAVA_HOME or PATH.
```

**UPDATE:** So the 2nd issue (JDK path) is resolved. I just had to close and open CMD again after setting the path for JDK. But the `The system cannot find the file C:\Users\USERNAME\JD Tools\activator-dist-1.3.12\bin\..\conf\sbtconfig.txt.` issue is still there.